# Overloading a member function pointed by a smart pointer

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, smart-pointers

I have a struct

```
struct A {
   void f() {}
   void g() {}
};
```

and a custom smart pointer holding a pointer to A:

```
struct P {
   ...
   A* a;
};
```

I would like to write P in such a way that that A::f() does not get called when I write

```
P p;
p->f();
```

Instead an overloaded function should be called. However, A::g() should still get called when I write

```
p->g();
```

I was hoping that I can achieve this by overloading P::operator-> but I didn't succeed. Any suggestions?

**Edit:** Here is what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
   void f() {}
   void g() {}
};

struct P {
   struct Wrapper
   {
      Wrapper(A* aa) : _a(aa) {}
      void f()
      {
         std::cout << "Overloaded\n";
      }
      A* operator->()
      {
         return _a;
      }
      private:
      A* _a;
   };

   Wrapper operator->()
   {
      return Wrapper(a);
   }
   private:
   A* a;
};

main()
{
   P p;
   p->f();
}
```

But this prints nothing at all because when I call p->f(), Wrapper::operator-> gets called instead of Wrapper::f().

Comment: if it is your custom smartpointer than you can do whatever you like. I dont really understand the question

Comment: What did you try? What problems did you have with that attempt? "Didn't succeed" isn't useful description.

Comment: make `->` return some wrapper that forwards calls to `g()` to call `Whatever::g()` and calls to `f()` to call `A::f()`

Comment: @tobi303 `operator->` is kind of special, in that it can only return a pointer that then gets used for the function call. You don't get any control over the actual function that gets called from that pointer.

Comment: @MarkRansom oh well, now I remember. And now I also get the point of the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your `P::operator->` would generally return an `A*` raw pointer. To get what you want, you need a *proxy* object that can be returned instead, which implements those functions.

```
class A_proxy
{
    A* p;
public:
    A_proxy(A* ptr) : p(ptr) {}
    void f() { /* do whatever crazy stuff you want here */ }
    void g() { p->g(); }
};

A_proxy* P::operator->()
{
    return &m_proxy;
}
```

Here's an alternate method based on objections raised in the comments. This one might run into undefined behavior because of the type punning of the pointer though.

```
struct A_proxy : public A
{
    void f() { /* as before, crazy stuff here */ }
};

A_proxy* P::operator->()
{
    return static_cast<A_proxy*>(a);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that in reality A is large and I don't want to repeat each one of its functions in the smart pointer. I just want to overload (disable) a single one.

Comment: @DraganVidovic you could have `A_proxy` publicly subclass from `A` so that you'd get forwarding for free.

Comment: A is heavy, I don't want to construct it again. I don't want to copy it, I want to refer to the original object passed to P during construction. If the proxy is derived from A then P is not a lightweight wrapper around a pointer which is what a smart pointer should be.

Comment: @DraganVidovic look closely at the code update. It's not making a copy of the object, it's casting the pointer.

Comment: Now I see. Indeed, it works, although it looks a bit scary. Thanks!